# Why I'm getting arithmetic overflow error when inserting bigint number to a bigint column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to insert a number to a column. Column datatype is BIGINT and I'm pretty sure that my number doesn't exceed the max value of BIGINT but still I get

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 40
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
The statement has been terminated.
```

My recent activity was I change the datatype of that column from INT to BIGINT. I think somewhere internally my column is still defined as INT.

Here is my script.

```
Insert into Customer(Cust_ID)
Select 2150000000
```

Column Cust_ID datatype is BIGINT in the designer. It is also the PRIMARY_KEY and many table reference it.

EDIT:
Here are some of the migration scripts

```
DROP TABLE dbo.Customer
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_Customer', N'Customer', 'OBJECT' 
GO
```

Comment: Can you include the SQL you ran to change the column type from `INT` to `BIGINT`?  In fact, this seems like the likely explanation for what you are seeing now.

Comment: I only used the script generated by SQL in designer when you change datatype. It is a big script  because is has many references.

Comment: The script drop all the constraints, Create a table named tmp_Customer (with BIGINT Cust_ID) then insert all data from old table to new Table

Comment: Something went wrong with your migration script, and you need to figure out what that is.

Comment: I added the migration script

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, there are triggers on the table

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the triggers and see if they are trying to inserts bigints into int fields.

Comment: ... also any computed columns?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid you give me a clue to solve my problem. Some of my contraints has scalar function with int parameter. Thank you

Comment: Great. When you solve it you can write it up and accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I already found the answer. My table has custom constraints which call scalar functions which requires an INT parameter.

Changing all those function's parameter to BIGINT solves the problem.